# Pass value to a function in a different Component

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have 2 components. one is a page and the other is a transition that slides over the page.. I wish to pass a value to a function in the transitionComponent but cant figure it out.. is @input the best way to do this or is there another way to directly call a function in another component ?

Edited with code example - I have slimmed down the main component to just focus on passing this value:

parent component:

```
            import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
            import {TransitionComponent} from '../../PageLoader/TransitionComponent';


            @Component({
                selector: 'home',
                templateUrl: './app/components/Homepage/list/index.html',
                directives: [ TransitionComponent]
            })


            export class HomepageListComponent implements OnInit {

                transitionState: string;

                    constructor() {
                        this.transitionState = this.transitionState;
                    }


                    ngOnInit() {

                        this.transitionState = "test";

                    }
            }
```

Child Component:

```
            import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

            @Component({
            selector: 'the-loader',
            template: `<div class="loader"></div>`,
            styles: [`
            .loader {
            background-color: black;
            height: 100%;
            width:100%;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            z-index:99999;
            }
            `]
            })




            export class TransitionComponent {

                @Input() transitionState;

                transitionStatus(transitionState) {
                    alert(transitionState);
                }


            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both components have parent-child scenario,you can exchange data from `Parent=>Child` and `Child => Parent` using **@Input, @ViewChild, EventEmitter, Injector** and so on...

If both components don't have any relation with each other, you can think of having `service (sharedService)`

**Update:**

I think what you want is to call a child function from parent and pass the data at a same time. For that you can use `@ViewChild API` shown here.
NOTE: you don't need to use @Input.

https://plnkr.co/edit/VaddcH?p=preview

with RC - https://plnkr.co/edit/iRLGfgO4zwUXDXzw9ot7?p=preview

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core'; // <---ViewChild added               
import {TransitionComponent} from '../../PageLoader/TransitionComponent';    

            @Component({
                selector: 'home',
                templateUrl: './app/components/Homepage/list/index.html',
                directives: [ TransitionComponent]
            })


            export class HomepageListComponent{    
               @ViewChild(TransitionComponent) vc:TransitionComponent;
               ngAfterViewInit()
               {
                   this.vc.transitionStatus('Angular2');
               } 
            }
```

---

```
        export class TransitionComponent {
            transitionStatus(transitionState:string) {
                alert(transitionState);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thats great info, havent used viewchild, eventemitter or injector yet. i have added some code examples above. it would be great to get your ideas as I cant seem to understand how to pass a string using @input

Comment: Thanks it looks great, Im using RC1 and its giving me this error now TypeError: Cannot read property 'transitionStatus' of undefined

Comment: Updated my answer with RC.

Comment: Just one more thing, if I wanted to access the value passed by the function in lets say the template html how would i do that.. I am trying this but its not outputting it template: `<div class="loader">THE VALUE IS {{value}}</div>`,

Comment: `transitionStatus(value){ this.someVar=value};` in html put `{{someVar}}`. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

In parent-child relatinship you can use:

ViewChild: when a parent component needs to access a member of it's child component, you can for example call a child's function from the parent.

@Input: allows you to pass a value from the parent to the child.

In your case I would use @input aprouch

Comment: I cant seem to figure this out for passing a string, I have updated my question above. I would be most greatful if you could look over it and give me some pointers