# how to pass datetime picker value to another component Angular

Tags: angular

I have a component which has a date picker

```
 <kendo-datepicker [(value)]="value" [format]="'yyyy-MM-dd'"></kendo-datepicker>
```

but this component is used in many components,from those components how can i get the value of DateTime picker?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/37730960/9880356 help you?

Comment: @Giannis if i have to get multiple values from child,still the best way is creating multiple @ouput?

Comment: If the case is just the value of the kendo-datepicker, I think it is easier (and faster) to choose the @Input-@Output way. So..yes, you can do this, but why not using a common service that will be shared by all the components if needed? Also note that a shared service will be the way to choose, if the components have no relation to each other and you need to pass some values.

Comment: @the components have relation because im using the datetimepicker in many components,but how should i use the service you are saying?is that the best practice?i appreciate if you make an example or send me a link

Comment: Please check this https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/